# Bigquery column name with multiple where clause

Tags: google-bigquery

below is my requirement.

prod is the prodname
count_group is the count of groupname that has count greater than 100 
count_success is the sum of all records that have category=AAA and package ='BBB'.
 count_user is the exact_count_distinct of userid column that have category=AAA and package ='BBB'

[image]

sample query below

```
    SELECT prod, 
count_group, 
Count_success, 
count_user
FROM
(SELECT
  prod,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(group) AS count_group,
SUM(IF(categoty = 'AAA' AND package ='BBB', 1, 0)) AS Count_success,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(userID) as count_user
 FROM
  [mytable]
WHERE
   Package ='FFF'

  AND (StartTime > ('2016-01-24 00:00:00 UTC')
    AND StartTime < ('2016-03-16 00:00:00 UTC')
    OR (StartTime > ('2016-03-26 00:00:00 UTC')
      AND StartTime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
      GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  2 DESC IGNORE CASE)
WHERE Count_group >100
```

Comment: please explain `count_group is the count of groupname that has count greater than 100`! the way you put it in your query is quite different and is translated as `show only prod with count_group greater than 100`! Are those two same? if not explain

Comment: yes, it means show only prod with count_group greater than 100

Comment: so in this case, what exactly problem with your query you have - from quick glance - it should work as you need

Comment: I was getting error in IF statement. I corrected out my mistake, syntax problem. Thanks

Comment: so it works now and question is addressed? please clarify

Comment: yes @MikhailBerlyant